# Correct sentence ending: X asked, “Y?”

Tags: punctuation, sentence-ends

Is it correct to use sentences in the following format?

> X asked, “...?”.

That is, a simple interrogative sentence enclosed within quotes followed by a period. Which is the correct sentence?

> - He asked, “How do you do?” She colloquially responds, “NM.”
> - He asked, “How do you do?”. She colloquially responds, “NM.”

Are there any alternatives to the above sentence?

Comment: I'm voting to close as General Reference. I'm sure there are other (and perhaps easier) ways to establish what (competent) writers *actually* do here, but one is just to look at the results returned by searching for ["voice said who are you"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22voice+said+who+are+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. You could do the same search in Google Internet, but you might need to ignore a handful of *incompetent* / casual writers.

Comment: The second option is incorrect and horrifying. The first is correct but boring. Barrie's suggestion is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reporting verbs would normally be in the same tense, that is, either *asked* and *responded* or *asks* and *responds*, and there is no point in using the adverb *colloquially* if you are reporting a conversation. The verb here would normally be *reply* rather than *respond*, it would normally follow the speech, and separate speeches will often occur on separate lines. I don’t know what *NM* means, but if you think your readers will know, then you can use it.

Some may disagree, but a comma after a reporting verb isn’t really necessary. There is also no need to add a full stop (or period) after a question mark and terminal quotation marks. It is clear where the sentence ends without it, and it only adds clutter to the page.

Taking those points into account, I would suggest:

> He asked “How do you do?”
>
> “NM” she replied.

Answer (score 0):

### Both seem fine.

Both of them returned no errors on multiple grammar check sites,
although I *prefer* the first option (as a native English speaker/writer).

Comment: This is a bug in the grammar check sites. I have never seen the combination of punctuation **?".** used, and I would strongly discourage anybody from using it.

Comment: I know, it seemed weird to me too, I'll check again. I personally prefer the first option too.

Answer (score 0):

A full stop is not needed at the ends of sentences with question (?) or exclamation (!) marks, as those are considered to be its own punctuation.
http://www.mantex.co.uk/2009/09/06/english-language-full-stop/